# Jquery click to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get it when the `#name` div is pressed, the page will scroll to `#profile-pic` but not having any luck.

```
$("#name").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#profile-pic").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qv9f7p6u/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Scroll To Section of Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991356/jquery-scroll-to-section-of-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the scrollable part is a div, not the page. You need to select the div to scroll.

```
$('#left-panel').animate({
```